# start second setInterval after x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I need to build a page that is scrolling up and down after x seconds. I just need to know how to start the second setInterval after a delay. Or if people got other solutions i'm open for anything!

here is the code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    scrollDown();
},8000);

setInterval(function() {
    scrollUp();
},8000);

function scrollDown() {

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#page2").offset().top
    }, 2000);
}

function scrollUp() {

    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#page1").offset().top
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Why not call setInterval in the scrollDown function rather than running two timers? Then again in the scrollUp function if needed so you get the required repetition

Comment: You can do this with just one `setTimeout`. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11795276/448232).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaner and more precise to do this with just one timer like so:

```
setInterval(scrollDown, 8000);

function scrollDown() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#page2").offset().top
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(scrollUp, 4000);
}

function scrollUp() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#page1").offset().top
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `setTimeout` that sets itself?

```
function setNext(up){
  setTimeout(function(){
     if(up) scrollUp(); 
     else scrollDown();
     setNext(!up);
  }, 8000);
}

scrollDown() //first time
setNext(true);
```

<strike>Disclaimer : I haven't tested it. (yet)</strike>

Here's the [working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/MkCzw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution, try this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    scrollDown();
},8000);

setTimeOut(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        scrollUp();
    },8000);
},1000);
```

because the setTimeOut function calls just once

Answer (score 0):

Others have already answered so I will only add that this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    scrollDown();
}, 8000);

setInterval(function() {
    scrollUp();
}, 8000);
```

Is the same as this:

```
setInterval(scrollDown, 8000);

setInterval(scrollUp, 8000);
```

You don't need an anonymous function for a callback if all you do in that anonymous function is call another named function - you can just pass the named function.

Answer (score -1):

```
setInterval(function() {
    scrollDown();
},8000);

setInterval(function() {
    scrollUp();
},8000 + 2000);
```

For what its worth, the above will have the exact same effect. But for code worded like your requirement, you could just:

```
setInterval(function() {
    scrollDown();
},8000);

setInterval(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        scrollUp();
    },8000);
2000);
```

Comment: I can tell you why he down voted you, the first part of your response doesn't do what was asked for the first time they will trigger at the same time.